# Записать данные в csv файл без кавычек?

Tags: python, csv

Пишу код, при записи данных в csv файл добавляются кавычки, а должно быть без них, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

```
import csv

data = [{
    'lastname': 'Иванов',
    'firstname': 'Пётр',
    'class_number': 9,
    'class_letter': 'А'
}, {
    'lastname': 'Кузнецов',
    'firstname': 'Алексей',
    'class_number': 9,
    'class_letter': 'В'
}, {
    'lastname': 'Меньшова',
    'firstname': 'Алиса',
    'class_number': 9,
    'class_letter': 'А'
}, {
    'lastname': 'Иванова',
    'firstname': 'Татьяна',
    'class_number': 9,
    'class_letter': 'Б'
}]

with open('dictwriter.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        f, fieldnames=list(data[0].keys()),
        delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writeheader()
    for d in data:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Выводится:

```
"lastname";"firstname";"class_number";"class_letter" 
"Иванов";"Пётр";9;"А"
"Кузнецов";"Алексей";9;"В"
```

А должно:

```
lastname;firstname;class_number;class_letter 
Иванов;Пётр;9;А 
Кузнецов;Алексей;9;В
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще-то заключать данные в кавычки - это стандартная практика при импорте-экспорте с экселем. Нужно отметить, что вы сами попросили кавычки, указав параметр `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`.  Попробуйте другой вариант этого параметра - `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`.

У меня получилось такое:

```
lastname;firstname;class_number;class_letter
Иванов;Пётр;9;А
Кузнецов;Алексей;9;В
Меньшова;Алиса;9;А
Иванова;Татьяна;9;Б
```

Но это не означает что кавычек не будет вовсе. Если скажем ваша строка будет содержать разрыв виде точки запятой, например вдруг гдето будет `'lastname': 'Иван;ов'`, то кавычки появятся. Для того, чтобы потом можно было бы правильно прочесть )

Как то так.